# regex alternation with awk

Tags: regex, awk

I have the following awk line in a function.

```
match($0,/'(.*)'/,a)
```

however I want to make it so that it will match `'(.*)'` or `"(.*)"`. I have tried writing it with different alternation syntax with no avail eg:

```
match($0,/'(.*)'|"(.*)"/,a)
```

however it doesn't want to work.

Just wondering if anyone can point out what is going on here.

Comment: We can usually provide more help the more info you provide. For example if you tell us in what way "it doesn't want to work" (syntax error? Unexpected output? No output? Something else?) and post some sample input and expected output and tell us if the script is in a file or executed from the command line and if you're on Windows or UNIX and which version of awk you are using (gawk? mawk? something else?) that would all be extremely useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this if it's a awk script:

```
match($0, /['"](.*)['"]/, a)
```

if not, (command line) :

```
match($0, /[\042\047](.*)[\042\047]/, a)
```

Comment: That will match strings with mismatched quotes as well.  For example `"abc'` will match.  You should probably use backreferences to play it safe.

Comment: Does `awk` even support backreferences?

Comment: @MarkReed no, it doesn't.

Comment: This seems to be fine 

match($0, /['"](.*)['"]/, a)

In my script thanks guys.

Comment: @Luke that will fail if you have mismatched quotes as Mr. Llama stated, and it will fail if you have multiple pairs of quoted segments on one line and if you DON'T have that then why are you bothering to populate an array and make it gawk-specific instead of just `match($0,/['"](.*)['"]/) {a=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)}` which would work in any awk.

Answer (score 3):

You need:

```
match($0,/\047([^\047]*)\047|"([^"]*)"/,a)
```

The `a` makes it gawk-specific. If you have your script stored in a file executed as `awk -f script` then you can change the `\047`s to `'`s.